# Insert Small Icon Image into a Button

Tags: html, image, button, containers, icons

I made a multiple choice trivia game and I want each answer choice to have a small image next to it. If you look at the code below you will see how everything is set up.

```
    <div id="gameChoices">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="left half">
          <div class="container"><button id="buttonOne" data-index="0"></button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left half">
          <div class="container"><button id="buttonTwo" data-index="1"></button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="left half">
          <div class="container"><button id="buttonThree" data-index="2"></button></div>
        </div>
        <div class="left half">
          <div class="container"><button id="buttonFour" data-index="3"></button></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

There 4 buttons and I use a script to generate the questions and answer choices. I want a small logo next to the text inside each button

[image]

**Ways that I have tried:**

```
<div class="container"><button id="buttonOne" data-index="0"><img src="rose.png" width="30" height="30"/></button></div>
```

No image appears at all

```
<div class="container"><img src="rose.png"><button id="buttonOne" data-index="0"></button></div>
```

Image appears before button on another line

```
<div class="container"><button id="buttonOne" data-index="0"><span><img src="rose.png" /></span></button></div>
```

No image appears at all

```
<div class="container"><button id="buttonOne" data-index="0"><img src="rose.png"></button></div>
```

No image appears at all

**Any help would be appreciated!**